# Really weird "[UIAccessibilityBundle setWhatever:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xnnnnnnn"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, llvm

So, I'm puzzled by a really weird crash occurring in my app.

**Background**: I have a class *CustomButton* overriding *UIButton*. Briefly, the interface looks like:

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation CustomButton
@synthesize loading = loading_;

- (id)init {
if ((self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom])) {
    [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"My Button", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self titleLabel] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[self titleLabel] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];

    [self setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 77, 0, 30)];

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:77 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *highlightedBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_highlighted.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:77 topCapHeight:0];
    [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setBackgroundImage:highlightedBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [self sizeToFit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setLoading:(BOOL)loading {

    if (loading_ != loading) {
       // Do fancy things
    }
}
@end
```

**Problem**: I'm trying to use the button in a class, so I have property and so on:

```
...
@property(nonatomic, strong) CustomButton *customButton;
...
@syntesize customButton = customButton_;
...
- (void)aMethod {
  self.customButton.loading = YES;
}
...
```

The button, of course, is initialized.
Then, upon executing the statement **self.bookButton.loading = YES**, I get this error

```
 2012-08-28 12:54:25.091 MyApp[9465:15803] -[UIAccessibilityBundle
 setLoading:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8650cc0
 2012-08-28 12:54:25.091 MyApp[9465:15803] *** Terminating app due
 to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
 '-[UIAccessibilityBundle setLoading:]: unrecognized selector sent to
 instance 0x8650cc0'
 *** First throw call stack: (0x1ead022 0x203ecd6 0x1eaecbd 0x1e13ed0 0x1e13cb2 0x26bf5 0x257ce 0xfa938f 0xfa96a4 0xfa99a7 0xfb8aea
 0x11600be 0x11603c7 0x1160436 0xf10e49 0xf10f34 0xc5bcaac 0xe04b54
 0x272e509 0x1de4803 0x1de3d84 0x1de3c9b 0x27887d8 0x278888a 0xee0626
 0x14cce 0x27b5 0x1) terminate called throwing an exception
```

I honestly have no idea about what to look for. It's either something really really stupid, or something really subdle. 
I've been searching on google/stackoverflow already of course, but I didn't manage to get an answer. 
Usually that error occurs, as far as I know, when the object doesn't "understand" the sent message, but this shouldn't be the case. I don't even get a warning from the compiler.

If you have even just an idea of what I could look for or you want more details, let me know, thanks.

**EDIT**: forgot to specify that I am using ARC.

**UPDATE**: In the answers below *Phillip Mills* said that it might have been a premature memory release issue. It's a good point, but Instrument didn't find any zombie. Moreover, I've put a log right before the crashy statement, where I try print information about the CustomButton object and few things related to a UIButton, like the title. Everything looks ok. The title is the one I've set, the frame is there and so on... so I believe the object (an actual UIButton) exists and it's also the expected one. The only thing is the "loading" property that messes everything up.

**SOLUTION**: the **init** method was the source of the problem. Instead of initializing an instance of the subclass of the button, it was initializing an instance of UIButton. So, conequentely, no "loading" properties could be found. Substituting **init** with **initWithFrame** and using the standard procedure to override the initializer, everything works great.
Still a mistery, though, the reason why I got **UIAccessibilityBundle** as the origin of the error and not a **UIButton**.

Comment: This is an unrelated memory issue, run with the memory profiling and see what's happening.

Comment: Off in a different direction...what does your CustomButton's `init` look like?

Comment: So, according to the `init`, CustomButton is not actually a subclass of UIButton but rather an instance of it.  It seems that, in a very real sense, @nneonneo is correct below and you **are** casting in your assignment to `customButton`.  I think what you have is effectively the same as if you'd typed `CustomButton *customButton = (CustomButton *)[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you get the message you do because, if I paste your code into a test app, I get: "[UIButton setLoading:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bd2040" and that makes much more sense.

Comment: That's the weird thing. I'm at least expecting an error related to the UIButton class.
Anyway, that initializer sucks way too much. It's true that it's not initializing a subclass of UIButton, but an instance of it. So, @nneonneo was on the right track.
I'll try to subclass the button like a human would do and than I'll see if the problem get solved.
Thanks for the help, I'll get back soon.

Comment: I wonder if the message difference is a version thing.  I tested using Xcode 4.4.1 and the iPad 5.1 simulator.

Comment: I tested with 4.3.2 and iPhone 5.1 simulator. I'll make a test with just the button and a client class asap and I let you know the result

Comment: Ok, done. I get the same error I got before, with UIAccessibilityBundle as the source of the problem. Might be a bug of llvm 3.1, but I'm just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you casting anything to `(CustomButton *)` in your app? Double-check the casts - you might be incorrectly casting something that's not a `CustomButton` and storing the result in the `customButton` property.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm initializing it during the setup, via **self.customButton = [[CustomButton alloc] init];**

Comment: So, after discussing with @Phillip Mills, I realized that in the initializer I'm actually creating an instance of UIButton and not a subclass. So that is 99% the issue, I'll try to refactor that button now and get back asap.

Answer (score 1):

The button is almost certainly being released prematurely and having its address re-used for a `UIAccessibilityBundle` object.  Try turning on zombies (or run Instruments to look for zombies) and you should see better information if the memory management problem isn't obvious.

Comment: The thing is that I'm working with ARC, so I'm not manually releasing any object. Anyway, I tried to print few object information right before the crashy statement, and I get all the right details belongin to the CustomButton. That is: frame size, titleLable with the title I set and so on. So I'm pretty sure the object is not released...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL loading;
@end
```

and

```
@implementation CustomButton
@synthesize loading = _loading;

- (id)init {
     ....
  }

- (void)setLoading:(BOOL)loading {

    if (self.loading != loading) {
       // Do fancy things
    }
}
@end
```

For all other instances of loading, use self.loading.

Without seeing the other parts of your code, this is my best guess.

Comment: Good point, considering that by default a property with ARC is strong. Nevertheless, I keep getting the same error.